# Having problems with file input and reading in Windows with Perl

Tags: windows, perl, file, input, io

I am trying to read a file in the same directory as the Perl script as input and read from it in Windows using Perl.

Code:

```perl
$inputFile =  getcwd . "/" . <STDIN>;
open (FILE, chomp($inputFile)) or die "Cannot open $inputFile: $!\n";   
@lines = <FILE>;
print "@lines\n";
```

The error I get is:

```
C:/Documents and Settings/username/workspace/test.pl  No such file or directory
```

Even though that file definitely does exist in that exact form in that exact directory.  I've also tried putting the "Documents and Settings" in quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value from `chomp` is not the chomped value. Factor out the `chomp` to before `open` and you should be fine.

The `getcwd` is needless, by the way; the concept of current directory means where to look in the absence of a full path.